# GAE executing GET request twice

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am newbie for GAE and am facing the issue of executing a request twice. Below is my simple request.

```
const express = require("express");
var app = new express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.json({ finalResponse: 1 });
  }, 5000);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

When I execute the request I see 2 requests in the network tab, this is because of internal redirect
[image: Internal Redirect 307]

My app.yaml look like below

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
service: server-api
instance_class: F4_1G
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

What configuration change is required to avoid the 307 redirect and enforce https by default

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is avoidable.  Think of it from the browser's perspective.  An `http` request ***does*** get redirected to `https`, and the URL in the address bar changes.  That is the desired behavior, and a 307 tells the user what happened. The response the user eventually sees is from the `https` request

Comment: I am actually passing the https request only but I am clueless why it first goes as http and then internally get redirected to https. I will try prepare a video to show a demo.

Comment: You've redacted the url in your image with a red line, but it sure looks like you first went to the `http://` url.

Comment: I just observed that this is happening just in chrome. I am making the https request itself but don't know why chrome is first sending a http request sometimes and it gets cancelled in the midway. Deleting the doman from hsts in chrome solves the issue.